Как объяснить выбор тире в стихотворении Лермонтова?
На каком основании поставлено тире, оно интонационное? Тогда ударение  должно ставиться на существительные храм и кумир.
Однако по Розенталю определение не обособляется только в ударной позиции (пункт 6). Кстати, все так и читают, что неправильно, как я думаю. Стих получается смазанным и неблагозвучным.
Как правильно прочитать стихотворение и объяснить знаки препинания?
  Расстались мы; но твой портрет
  Я на груди моей храню:
  Как бледный призрак лучших лет,
  Он душу радует мою.
  И новым преданный страстям,
  Я разлюбить его не мог:
  Так храм оставленный — все храм,
  Кумир поверженный — все бог!

P.S. Кстати, первое двоеточие лучше заменить запятой.
И хотелось бы изменить строку Я разлюбить его не мог / Я позабыть его не мог. Любить двоих вряд ли получится, а помнить можно. Тогда восприятие духовного мира поэта получается более объемным и интересным. Ну это я так думаю))
Как читают стихотворение.  (Мне кажется, мало кто умеет читать стихи.)
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/655419388336694810
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/18292615745353377198 https://yandex.ru/video/preview/9051633661490149690
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Стихотворение М.Ю. Лермонтова имеет интересную историю: написанное в 1831 году, оно было редактировано в 1837 году. В чем причина?  Возможно, изменился весь стиль творчества поэта после встречи с Белинским. Тогда "младого гения  (в 1837 году поэту было 23 года) очень качественно повозили фэйсом о тейбл». Из статьи.
Другой вариант — переадресация. Стихотворение было написано Лермонтовым в 1837 году на основе своего раннего варианта, при этом две последние строки 1831 года, посвященного Е. Сушковой, перешли в новый вариант без изменений. По мнению большинства исследователей, адресатом стихотворения являлась Варвара Лопухина-Бахметева.
В любом случае правка оказалась очень удачной. Стихотворение вызывает интерес и в наше время, выглядит как образец поэтического творчества.
